# Chunked HTTP response does not come through completely

Tags: http, tcp, tunnel

Consider the following setup

> 

```
 +-------+            +--------+           +----------+
 |       |            |        |           |          |
 |       +----------->+        +---------->+          |
 |       | TCP TUNNEL |        |    HTTPS  |          |
 +-------+            +--------+           +----------+
  User                  SSH Server         Web server
```

**User** Performs a HTTP GET request to 127.0.0.1:8888

**User** is being TCP tunneled from 127.0.0.1:8888 to **SSH Server, using SSH port forwarding**

**User** is being TCP tunnel from **SSH Server** to Web server which responds with **Transfer-Encoding: chunked**

**User** receives only first 700KB of data and the connection hangs.

The same thing works perfectly when using a fixed Content-Length.

#### Investigation

When performing the same HTTP GET request from the SSH server itself - **The whole response is received**

When performing the same HTTP GET request from another type of TCP tunneling (i.e SOCKS from USER to SSH SERVER) - **The user receives only 700kb of data**

When performing a HTTP GET request through the tunnel, and the HTTP server responds with a fixed-length body, **all of the data is received**

#### The riddle

Where should we start looking? Why does the HTTP GET works perfectly when running directly from SSH server, but does not work when tunneled through it?

Comment: Does the entire SSH session hang, or only the specific tunnelled connection?

Comment: @user1686 only the tunnel. This also happens if I replace the SSH tunnel with another kind of tunneling protocol (i.e SOCKS client/server instead of SSH client/server)

Comment: Do you mean _actual_ SOCKS (e.g. Dante), or do you mean SOCKS with SSH using `ssh -D`?

Comment: @user1686 yes actual SOCKS (not using ssh -D to rule out a problem with SSH)